# Pylint: "locally defined disables" still give warnings. How to suppress them?

Tags: pylint

I work with a software framework which has a couple of classes with method names containing capital letters (due to C++ wrappers). This is of course not PEP8 and `pylint` shows the corresponding error `C0103`. I also added `C0111` to the list to ignore the missing docstrings for some methods, like this:

```
def Configure(self): # pylint: disable=C0103,C0111
```

It works, however now I get warnings because of the local disablings:

```
Class: I0011 -> locally disabling C0103
Class: I0011 -> locally disabling C0111
```

How should I suppress them?

Comment: I generally just ignore the locally-disabled warnings, though I'd be interested in knowing if and how they can be disabled.  As an aside, you can give symbolic names instead of obsure numbers, e.g. `# pylint: disable=invalid-name,missing-docstring`.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. By ignoring, I guess you mean adding a "disable=I0011" line in the pylint config, don't you?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK, so obviously one has to ignore the ignore-warning explicitly. One can do this in the  pylint config file: if you don't have one, simply generate a standard configuration via

```
pylint --generate-rcfile > pylint.rc
```

and uncomment the line with `disable=...` and add `I0011` to the list. This suppresses all warnings regarding "locally defined disablings".

The other method is to add the following line to the beginning of a file (or block, whatever), if you don't want to suppress the warning globally:

```
#pylint: disable=I0011
```

Comment: Prefer symbolic names, eg locally-disabled instead of I0011, they are much easier to read and remember (numerical ids will be disabled at some point). Also, you can give options to --generate-rcfile to get "preconfigured" rc file, eg `pylint ---disable=locally-disabled -generate-rcfile > pylint.rc`